# What is the status of Earth in Firefly?

Tags: firefly, serenity

Serenity makes it clear that colonists left Earth due to overpopulation and resource deficiency. And it's referred to as Earth-that-was. But do we have any indication that Earth is actually depopulated?

Comment: Everyone's dead, Dave.